# Restore database timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm trying to restore a database by using the following code

```
string Restore = @"RESTORE DATABASE [" + dbname+ "] FROM DISK = N'" + filePath + "' WITH REPLACE, FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
SqlCommand RestoreCmd = new SqlCommand(Restore, con);
RestoreCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it returns me a timeout expired error, I have set connect timeout=300 in the connectionstring

but by running only the t-sql script
RESTORE DATABASE [dbname] FROM DISK = N'filepath' WITH REPLACE, FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
it works fine

what should i do to fix this?

Comment: Not 100% sure as I have not done this for ages, but I believe there is a timeout on the SqlCommand too that you can specify

Comment: TYVM Ryk, I didn't know the solution was so simple, yes ,it worked! sqlcommand.commandtimeout is the time that a single command might take to run, while connect timeout setting in connectionstring is the time for establishing the connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the CommandTimeout property of you RestoreCmd like so:

```
RestoreCmd.CommandTimeout = 300;
```